# Laravel - Failed to authenticate on SMTP server with .. using 2 possible authenticators

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, swiftmailer, mailgun

I saw this questions were asked many times. I tried many of them and nothing working. I am using laravel and mailgun api to send email.

I am geting this error `Failed to authenticate on SMTP server with username "postmaster@noreplay.padelmatch.se" using 2 possible authenticators` and also in my dedicated server log I get

```
2018-05-30 13:37:32 dovecot_login authenticator failed for 
(domain.com) [198.20.114.174]:40412: 535 Incorrect authentication 
data (set_id=email@sub.subdomain.com)

2018-05-30 13:37:38 SMTP connection from (domain.com) 
[198.20.114.174]:40412 lost
```

I also created a email account with same name (`email@sub.subdomain.com`) but still doesn't work.

In my .env file I have a set up like this

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.mailgun.org
MAIL_PORT=25
MAIL_USERNAME=email@sub.domain.com
MAIL_PASSWORD=xxxxxxx
MAILGUN_SECRET=xxxxxxx
MAILGUN_DOMAIN=sub.domain.com
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null
```

Any idea how can I solve it?

Thank you.

Comment: I've used 587 port with mailgun... Do you use https connection?

Comment: no. only http connection

Answer (score 3):

I solved it. Actually it was a stupid thing. Since I was using mailgun so I don't need to use smpt as it is causing the issue. So in mail driver, I used MAIL_DRIVER=mailgun and that's the solution for my case :). Hope it helps some lonely googler....

Comment: It certainly saved me! Thanks

Comment: Can you please add full config?