# Failed to authenticate on SMTP server with username "... using 2 possible authenticators in Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, mailgun

I was able to send mail (ordering process) a few months ago on my website and then today, I got an error message like that on Laravel.
I use mailgun 0$ per month plan. I tried to register a new domain today for another website mailing process on Mailgun. Please help me if you ever faced one like that. It was okay till last month and then I found out today. I didn't edit anything on my hosting for sure. : (

My .env file looks like this.

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.mailgun.org
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=mailaddress
MAIL_PASSWORD=passwords
```

[image: The error]

Comment: what error you getting can you please share a screen shot of that

Comment: I added the error screenshot :D

Comment: this error occuer when you using a secure account goto your mail account seting and set less secure account

Comment: I think mailgun updated security recently then : ( 
Do you know how to do it for mailgun?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Laravel - Failed to authenticate on SMTP server with .. using 2 possible authenticators](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50613906/laravel-failed-to-authenticate-on-smtp-server-with-using-2-possible-authent)

Answer (score 1):

Mailgun has probably made some changes. If you log into Mailgun and reset the SMTP password and use the new password in your config file. In my case this solved the problem.